# IIS Express повторно не запускается в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, iis

В общем, есть сайт, который я запускаю в Visual Studio.

Первый раз все четко запускается, а если перезапустить сессию дебага, то второй раз он не запускается.
Если смотреть в трей, то IIS Express там отсутствует.

Проблему решает только перезапуск Visual Studio, но опять же, только на 1 раз и приходится каждый раз перезапускать студию.

В чем может быть проблема?

При этом в решении есть другой сайт, под такой же фреймворк .NET Framework 4.6.1, который успешно стартует при повторном запуске...

Не понимаю в какую сторону копать...

**UPD**

А если в Project URL выставить такой же порт, как у проекта, который многократно стартует, то все четко... Почему так может быть?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, это странное решение, но если не пробовали:

- проверьте никто ли больше не использует порт, который вас интересует
  с помощью `netstat -a -b` в cmd(под админом)
- попробуйте .vs папку удалить. (в частности может конфликтует файл
  [solution_folder].vs\config\applicationhost.config).
- далее откройте [project_name].csproj.user (если таковой имеется) и проверьте (после того как перестаёт IIS Express запускаться) тот ли
  там порт в `WebProjectProperties` для `IISUrl` указан в строке.
- так же если с этим всё-таки что-то не так, можно пойти в {Project Properties} -> Web и нажать "Create Virtual Directory" кнопку..

Понимаю, что это не панацея, но я бы проверил данные варианты